# customize ' who is online' 's block

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am very beginner in drupal. I want to show users how many people are gust and how many people are online now. but i don't want to show users the username of online people. The drupal shows the username of online users by default.
I want to change some sentence in 'how is online's ' block too.
how can I do that? 
I have searched a lot. I found s.th that are confusing. 
thanks

Answer (score -1):

you could give the [User Stats](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_stats) Module (Dev-Version for D7) a try!

it has a views integration, so i think it should be possible to achieve!